# Solution to the integral $\int_0^\infty dx \frac{x^4 e^x}{\left(e^x-1\right)^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to solve the following integral: 
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty dx \frac{x^4 e^x}{\left(e^x-1\right)^2}
\end{equation}
It is the Debey integral in the limit $x_D \longrightarrow \infty $. There is no integral free primitive to this function, so I tried to solve it via Cauchy's redidue theorem as well as Feynman's integration. None of it was succesfull.

Any help whould be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} x^4 e^{-x}(1-e^{-x})^{-2}~ dx=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}k~ x^4 e^{-k x}= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{4!}{k^4}=24~ \zeta(4)= 24\frac{\pi^4}{90}=\frac{4\pi^4}{15}. $$

Comment: Sorry for the typo both are $\pi^4.$.